# how to fix Error: The argument type 'Function' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'void Function()?'. - 'Function' is from 'dart:core'

Tags: flutter

I am trying to passe a function from the main.dart to a widget and I get this error:

> Error: The argument type 'Function' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'void Function()?'.

- 'Function' is from 'dart:core'.

FilterScreen class

```
import 'package:delimails/widgets/main_drawer.dart';  import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class FilterScreen extends StatefulWidget {   static const routeName = '/filter';    final Function saveFilters;

  FilterScreen(this.saveFilters);

 @override   
_FilterScreenState createState() => _FilterScreenState(); }

class _FilterScreenState extends State<FilterScreen> {  


 @override   Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('Your favorites'),
          actions: [
           IconButton(icon : Icon(Icons.save), onPressed: **widget.saveFilters**)
          ],
      ), 

// main class : class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {   // This widget is the root of your application.   @override   _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState(); }

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {  Map<String, bool> _filters = {    'gluten' : false,    'lactose' : false,    'vegan' : false,    'vegetarian' : false,  };

  void _setFilters (Map<String, bool> filterData){    print('we are here !');  } 

  @override   Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
          primaryColor: Colors.cyan[300],
          accentColor: Colors.orange[100],
          canvasColor: Color.fromRGBO(255, 254, 229, 1),
          fontFamily: 'Releway',
          textTheme: ThemeData.light().textTheme.copyWith(
              bodyText1: TextStyle(color: Color.fromRGBO(20, 51, 51, 1)),
              bodyText2: TextStyle(color: Color.fromRGBO(20, 51, 51, 1)),
              headline6: TextStyle(
                fontSize: 20,
                fontFamily: 'RobotoCondensed',
                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
              ))),
      // home: CategoriesScreen(),
      routes: {    
        '/': (ctx) => TabsScreen(),
        '/categories': (ctx) => CategoriesScreen(),
        CategoryMealsScreen.routeName: (ctx) => CategoryMealsScreen(),
        MealDetailScreen.routeName: (ctx) => MealDetailScreen(),
        FilterScreen.routeName : (ctx) => FilterScreen(_setFilters),
      },
      
      
    );   } }
```

Answer (score 0):

It is hard to say with your unformatted code.

But it looks like you define your variable/parameter `saveFilters` as a `Function` which could be any function possible (`String Function(BuildContext)` or `List<int> Function(int, int)` etc) which wouldn't match the type expected for the parameter `onPressed` of the `IconButton` (`void Function()` or `VoidCallback`).

Can you try to specify explicitly the type of `saveFilters` to `void Function()`?

```dart
class FilterScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  FilterScreen(this.saveFilters);

  static const routeName = '/filter';
  final void Function() saveFilters;

  @override
  _FilterScreenState createState() => _FilterScreenState();
}

// ... The rest of your code
```